# Validating C# class fields using custom Attributes

Tags: c#-4.0

```
class Employee
{
  [ValueNotEmpty("Empty strings not allowed"]
  public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

`"ValueNotEmpty"` is a custom attribute.I tried using YABOV library but i have to call Validate method of the base class explicitly to validate the custom attributes and return the validation messages.

In the implementation class, i use reflection to set values on `"Name"` field.When i set value on `"Name"` field i expect the try block to throw an exception saying `"Empty strings not allowed"`.Is there any way i can do this without explicitly calling a method to validate the class when i set value for the field?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few thoughts to this problem:

If your property calls a PropertyChanged event, there might be a mechanism which uses this to validate it. For instance in combination with data binding. If you don't have PropertyChanged, you need to call Validate somewhere explicitly, unless you're using AOP.

Executing code when you just set a value would require AOP. In .Net standard libraries, there is no AOP technology included, you would have to integrate one (eg. Spring). AOP requires code generation or byte-code enhancement. So it's not a trivial thing.

Comment: Stefan, thanks for the reply.I have nearly 40 classes and each class contains 10 to 15 properties.I wanted to automate the validation instead of using "IF"'s but i guess you are right , explicitly the validate method should be called.

Answer (score 0):

You could try inheritiing from IDataErrorInfo and the implementing as below, but I suppose that this is what you mean by calling the validation explicitly.

```
public class Employee : IDataErrorInfo
{
  public string Name{get;set;}

  string IDataErrorInfo.Error {get {return null;}}

  string IDataErrorInfo.this[string propertyName]
  {
    get { return this.GetValidationError(propertyName);}
  }

  string GetValidationError(string propertyName)
  {
    string error = null;
    switch(propertyName)
    {
      case "Name":
        error = ValidateName();
        break;
     default:
        error = "Unknown proeprty";
        break;
    }
  }

  string ValidateName()
  {
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Name))
    {
      return null;
    }
    return "Empty Name";
  }
}
```